# Whats the best way to start long running methods in modules in Azure IoTEdge?

Tags: c#, azure-iot-edge

I need a keep-alive function running as long as the device is running. The method is inside a module. I am experiencing that it stops running after 3-10 hours.

```
// Async method to send keepalive signals
private static async void SendKeepaliveToCloudMessagesAsync()
{
    int keep_alive_counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            String timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("u");
            String activity_type = "Device-Keepalive";
            // Create JSON message
            var telemetryDataPoint = new
            {
                timestamp,
                activity_type,
                device_id,
                keep_alive_counter
            };
            var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
            keep_alive_counter++;

            // Add a custom application property to the message.
            // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
            message.Properties.Add("keepaliveAlert", (keep_alive_counter < 30) ? "true" : "false");

            // Send the telemetry message
            await s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] > Sending Keepalive message: {1}", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("u"), messageString);

            await Task.Delay(s_keepaliveInterval * 1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Send keepalive Failed! {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, for 3-10 hours, but then suddenly stops, and I dont receive the keep-alive messages on IoTHub.

I managed to get the following message from the logs:

```
Send keepalive Failed! System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IoT Client'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.DefaultDelegatingHandler.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.DefaultDelegatingHandler.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<OpenAsyncInternal>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.EnsureOpenedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<SendEventAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendEventAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.SendEventAsync(Message message)
   at MotionDetection.Program.SendKeepaliveToCloudMessagesAsync() in /app/Program.cs:line 439
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when it stopped? Are you sure the module stops? Or is only the Edge Hub not receiving any messages anymore?

Comment: I have added to error-message from the logs to the OP, and realized that the s_deviceclient is is disposed by unknown reasons.

Comment: Currently, I am testing a version, with checks for deviceclient == null, and having a local device-client instance. Not sure why that is needed...

Comment: Are you in the latest version of the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client nuget Version? Also are you on the latest IoT Edge Version 1.0.8? If not, please update

Comment: I have upgraded IoT Edge to 1.0.8-2 as soon as it came out, but I did not do a "dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client --version 1.21.0" in all module dirs. Just did that, will revert with results tomorrow. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the error you are seeing should not happen, I can still answer the actual question:

The way you constructed your module to send messages for an unlimited amount of time looks fine and should generally work. Actually, one of the samples of the IoT Edge team in the official repolooks very much like yours, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/edge-modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/src/Program.cs#L176) (for the case when `SendUnlimitedMessages()` is `true`).

Maybe just follow their example and implement a shutdown handler as well for a clean exit strategy.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I think the upgrade made the systems run perfectly since yesterday without interruptions. I will add the shutdown handler. Thanks for your valuable hints. :)